# display a variable without changing the code

Tags: php

I have a variable `$_SESSION['warning']` every time I used this variable I only defined what it contains for example

```
$_SESSION['warning'] = 'there is something wrong with the database';
```

I would like to display "`echo`" the function when it is assigned. the problem is.. I have used the variable `$_SESSION['warning']` in many locations and on different files. it will take a long time to fix each one of them add the line

```
echo $_SESSION['warning'];
```

is there anything on php that I can add in the beginning of each file that treats "`$_SESSION['warning']`" to be echoed when it is assigned?

Comment: An include? You'd still have to go through and edit each file to add the include of course, unless there is an existing included file you can add it to.

Comment: there is an include file

Comment: but I do not know what to put in it.. to make $_SESSION['warning'] to be displayed

Comment: `if(!empty($_SESSION['warning'])) echo $_SESSION['warning'];`

Comment: Thanks !! I never thought of that!

Comment: "*it will take a long time to fix each one…*" - Why? Use batch processing and regex-replace the assignment with a function call.

Comment: Wants to make change without changing?

Comment: @DarylGill there is a difference between changing the code .. and adding a line in the begining of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the echo to your include file. Something like:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['warning'])) echo $_SESSION['warning'];
```

Presumably you'd also want to clear the value once it's displayed so it doesn't continue getting displayed on every page after that.

Comment: But the include is at the top of the file, and `$_SESSION['warning']` will not yet be assigned there?

Comment: Bergy .. if it was assigned on another page.. it will be assigned on the page that includes the code that @Mark Parnell because it is a session variable not a normal variable